# Need help partitioning drives

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a Hitachi 500 GB hard drive, and I dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 7. I am thinking of creating a new ext4 filesystem drive from some existing drive. This is to move my home directory over that drive. Just in case, I mess up with my system alot, so wanted to permanently move the home directory to a safe location.

Currently, my partition looks like  [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG3H6.jpg)

I would like to shrink ANY of the drives so that a new drive ~30 GB is created.

Thanks.

Comment: The only drive you will be able to shrink is `W` you can use the same tool you show in your screenshot to do this.

Comment: @Ramhound The tool shown in the picture is Windows Disk Management, which's unable to resize partition. **NEW: SORRY, it has the ability.**

Comment: @Noverull - Of course it does I wouldn't have suggested it if it didn't.

Comment: I find you have many many files occupying disk. If you give 30G to new partition, then there will leave little. Do you like to do it anyway?

Comment: @Ramhound, there's no option to shrink `W:`, shat should I do?

Comment: right-click the volume that you want to shrink, and then click Shrink Volume(via [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx))